# javascript for addEventListener not assigning correctly

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

when I click on any of the Selects on my page the only thing the function tells me is it is using the last Select.

Say I have 6 Selects on my page, I first assign a `addEventListener` to them all passing the id as a parameter and then when changing any of them I expect the alert to say "OK+the select I chose", but what I get is always "OK gubeSelect6".

Why when I choose 1-5 does it not show the correct thing?  Is my `addEventListener` wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

```
function resetValues(ddl) {
    alert("OK " + ddl);
}

var selects = document.getElementsByName('gubeSelect');
var sel;

console.log(selects);

for(var z = 0; z < selects.length; z++){
    console.log(z + " " + selects[z].id + " " + selects[z].name);
    sel = selects[z];
    document.getElementById(sel.id).addEventListener("change", function () {
        resetValues(sel.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes I can see how it is a duplicate, however searching stackoverflow didn't give me the answer, primarily because of the terminology in use.  I wouldn't have ever thought to look for javascript closure in loops. Thanks though, a very useful article and I will refer back to it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
document.getElementById(sel.id).addEventListener("change", function () {
        resetValues(this.id);
    });
```

by the time the event happens sel.id will be always 6.
You need to address the element you added the listener to.

Comment: As it is, this answer doesn't explain the actual problem, nor why this would work.

Comment: Does this satisfy you?

Comment: I'm used to variables being sorted at run time, not after the fact so my thinking was the addEvent would add a string to the anonymous function which is obvioulsy not what is happening.  I've still learning javascript so this was new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `resetValues(this.id);` instead of `resetValues(sel.id);`

I think when you call `resetValues(sel.id);` here `sel` variable is sending reference to the function. And when you change value of `sel` it will change all value of previous `sel`s

Comment: I only gave the solution to user733421 because he came in first but your explanation helped.